# How to make a HTML text multiline using a C# bind in a blazor project?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a `Blazor` project with a ClientSide Razor Page. On that page I want to show a multiline text, for example:

*Series not found*
*Error message*

But the text is found in a C# string using a `@bind`.

I have tried using the normal `\n` to make a newline. It did pickup that it was command, but it placed a "space" in the text instead of making a new line.

I have also tried writing `<br />` in the text, but then it just wrote that in the text.

My razor page:

```
<p>@resultString</p>

@code {
    string resultString = "Series not found \nError message";
}
```

With the input in the code snippet I would expect the following output:

*Series not found*
*Error message*

Comment: `<pre>@resultString</pre>`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using Razor templates. \r\n, Envirnoment.Newline, and anything else cannot make the compiler budge.

Here is a working solution using Razor Template:

```
<p>@resultString</p>

@code {
    RenderFragment resultString =  @<p>Series not found <br />Error message</p>;

}
```

Update:
You can also use this:

```
MarkupString  resultString = (MarkupString) $"Series not found <br />Error message";
```

Update 2:
From the documents:

> **Render raw HTML** Blazor normally renders strings using DOM text nodes, which means that any markup they may contain will be ignored
>   and treated as literal text. This new feature lets you render special
>   MarkupString values that will be parsed as HTML or SVG and then
>   inserted into the DOM.
>
> WARNING: Rendering raw HTML constructed from any untrusted source is a
>   major security risk!
>
> Use the MarkupString type to add blocks of static HTML content.

```
@((MarkupString)myMarkup)

@functions {
    string myMarkup = "<p class='markup'>This is a <em>markup string</em>.</p>";
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think it's a good idea to render the raw html tag because it is so dangerous most of the time.

As for your question, I would suggest you should add one line **`CSS`** code to display the line breaking:

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line" >@resultString</p>

@code {
    string resultString = "Series not found \nError message";
}
```

#### Demo

[image]

Comment: Or use [`white-space: pre-wrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) to maintain spacings.

Answer (score 2):

You can always go for the simple approach: split and loop

```
@foreach (var line in resultString.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
        <p>@line</p>
 }

@code {

    public string resultString  => "Series not found \nError message";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `MarkupString`, it is important to ensure that the lines are correctly encoded. One simple way to ensure that is to use the following helper method:

```
public static class HtmlHelper
{
   public static MarkupString RenderMultiline(string textWithLineBreaks)
    {
        var encodedLines = (textWithLineBreaks ?? string.Empty)
            .Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' })
            .Select(line => HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(line))
            .ToArray();

        return (MarkupString)string.Join("<br />", encodedLines);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div>
    @HtmlHelper.RenderMultiline($"This text goes over\nmultiple lines\neven with {userinput}");
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label title="msg" class="col-form-label fw-bold fs--1">@((MarkupString)Msg) </label>

@code{    
string Msg = "Password is not <b>strong</b> enough!";
}
```

Use (`MarkupString`) in razor to display html in string